# How to correctly intepret the following clause?

Tags: て-form, parsing

This is a paragraph taken from a novel. It describes an outlawish group of people who decided to run away from civilized society.

Simplified part with bolded clause that I'm having trouble with:

> 彼らは、**他の大多数がそうするように順応して我を殺す**ことを良しとしない（～なかった）逃亡者だ。

What does the bolded part mean, exactly? Is it "adapting （順応する）　to what majority does （大多数がそうする, with そう implying 我を殺す?）, commit suicide （我を殺す）?" In other words, committing suicide like majority would do? Could 我を殺す also imply simply "repressing oneself (one's antisocial urges)"?

Full paragraph:

> 警察、親、教師、あるいは極道｛マフィア｝から、生きるために逃亡してこの場に篭るアウトロー。表で生きられないと悟った彼らは、他の大多数がそうするように順応して我を殺すことを良しとせず、同類を求めて自らの居場所を作った勇気ある逃亡者だ。

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

そうする refers to 順応して我を殺す (= 社会/環境に順応して、自分/自我を押し殺す)

[我]{が}を殺す is like "repress oneself/ego", not "commit suicide".

So I think it would be like:

> [(他の大多数がそうするように)順応して我を殺す]ことを良しとせず・・・
>   (They) are not willing to [adapt themselves to the circumstances (or, adjust to the society) and repress their ego (as the majority do)], ...